# I bought a Mac that did not come with recovery media. Can I reinstall my original OS?

Tags: macos, internet-recovery

For the last few years Macs have not shipped with recovery media. Instead, you could boot into a mode where the Mac OS X installer is downloaded from the internet.

With OS X Mavericks now a free update for ANY Mac that supports it, does the internet installer still install your original OS, or does it helpfully (or, perhaps, annoyingly) just install Mavericks?